# What is the best way to manage private routes with solana-wallet-adapter?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, react

Currently, I am using a combination of local storage and public key to managing the private-public route. But this approach fails when user decides to revoke access to this application

```
const PrivateRoutes: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathIsProtected = !nonProtecedRoute.includes(router.pathname);
  const { publicKey } = useWallet();


  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("walletName");
    const isUserAuthenticated = Boolean(data || publicKey);

    if (!isUserAuthenticated && pathIsProtected) {
      router.push("/");
    } else if (isUserAuthenticated && !pathIsProtected) {
      router.push("/mint");
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [publicKey]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to manage this at present.

Because the authorizedness of an app is not synchronized with your web frontend, let alone your web server, it’s impossible to know on initial load whether a prior authorization is still valid.

The best you can do is to *optimistically* try to access resources that you presume the user still owns or is still authorized to sign for, and invalidate their cached authorization if you discover that to no longer be the case.

Comment: I have many thoughts on technologies we could develop to (re)authorize people on initial load, but those are going to take some time to materialize as prototypes.

Comment: I guessed so. The only way I figured we could have it is to authenticate via backend with cookies and start polling to detect wallet change or disconnect